# How to view network weights and bias during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the below code. 
I would like to see how the weights and bias changes during training. 
Ideally I would like to see it in tensorboard. 
Would someone be able to show me how to do this.

```py
from time import time

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
x = scaler.fit_transform(np.array([[1965.0], [1980.0]])).reshape(-1,1)
y = scaler.fit_transform(np.array([[320.0], [345.0]])).reshape(-1,1)
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(time()), write_grads=True)
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss="mean_squared_error")
model.fit(x=x, y=y, epochs=1000, callbacks=[tensorboard])

yHat = model.predict(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard), all you need to do maybe is just run the command line:

`tensorboard --logdir=logs`

Notice that the logdir setting is pointing to the root of your log directory.

Comment: When I do this I don't see the weights and bias. I only see the loss value per epoch.

Comment: @Funzo To be able to visualize the parameters: the model.fit() function must has validation_split param, else histograms cannot be visualized; and the value of histogram_freq > 0 always (otherwise histograms can't be computed). Maybe you should try:

`model.fit(x=x, y=y, epochs=1000, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[tensorboard])` and `tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(time()), histogram_freq=1, write_graph=True, write_grads=True)`

Comment: It's written right in the "Arguments" part of the [document](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard) btw

Comment: I assume you just need to visualize the weights, because the bias is constant and untrainable